# Use case statement in the SELECT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the field marital status with values 'S','D','M'or'U'
The query should look for all single persons and treat all persons that are Divorced and Unknown also as single.
This is what I was trying so far

```
Select *
from marketing_list 
where 
   Marital_Status = 
      Case 
        When Marital_Status = 'D' Then 'S' 
        When Marital_Status = 'U' Then 'S'
      End
```

Comment: `this is an assignment and my tutor want us to use a case statement in the select clause ` Why is an assignment being answered?

Comment: That is a case expression in the where clause, not a "case statement in the select clause."

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `in`?

```
Select * from Marketing_List
where Marital_Status in ('D','S','U')
```

Or alternatively (assuming no NULL values):

```
Select * from Marketing_List
where Marital_Status <> 'M'
```

If you have to use a case statement (as commented), the syntax should be:

```
Select * from Marketing_List
where case when Marital_Status in ('S','D','U') then 'S' else 'M' end = 'S'
```

or

```
Select * from Marketing_List
where case when Marital_Status = 'D' then 'S' 
           when Marital_Status = 'U' then 'S' 
      Else Marital_Status end = 'S'
```

Comment: Argh, you beat me to it! When my upvote replenishes I will +1 you.

Comment: this is an assignment and my tutor want us to use a case statement in the select clause

Comment: @user2127184 I have edited to add examples of how to do this if you need a case statement.

Comment: thanks @JohnOdom this works..really appreciate it..one love from Jamaica

Comment: @user2127184.  I am glad to hear this works for you.  If your question is resolved, please consider marking the answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

With your codes defined like they are, a `CASE` statement is unnecessary for just filtering.  Use an `IN` statement in the WHERE clause instead.

```
SELECT * 
FROM marketing_list 
WHERE Marital_Status IN ('D','S','U')
```

Comment: ummm..I guess this works but I think I'm supposed to search for all single person and at the same treat 'U' and 'D' persons as SINGLE

Answer (score 1):

Simple if you change the M to NULL

```
Select *
from marketing_list 
where 
   Marital_Status = 
      Case 
        When Marital_Status = 'M' Then NULL
        ELSE Marital_Status           
      End
```

Answer (score 1):

In one of the comments, you say:

> this is an assignment and my tutor want us to use a case statement in the ***select*** clause

So it sounds like, what you really want, is to select all rows, while converting the marital status in the results using a `CASE` statement.  That makes more sense, otherwise, using an `IN` clause is more appropriate.

Here is the query you would want:

```
select m.*,
       case when m.marital_status IN ('D', 'U')
            then 'S'
            else m.marital_status
       end as concise_marital_status
  from marketing_list m
```